# Как изменить текст в меню, которое при наведении выезжает вправо

Tags: html, css

У меня есть задание сделать меню, которое  при наведении на него курсора мыши плавно выезжает вправо и в части которая выдвигается будет какая-то информация, но щас у меня есть проблема с текстом, текст выводится в одной строке и из-за этого слова непонятные, как решить эту проблему исходя из моего кода [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p class="p">Обратная связь</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  font-size: 20px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 130px;
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(33, 32, 36);
  position: right;
  height: 138px;
}

div:hover .p {
  position: relative;
  right: -275px;
}

div:hover::after {
  writing-mode: initial;
  content: "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, eligendi!";
  color: white;
}

p {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  height: 130px;
}
```

Comment: А почему нельзя сделать просто блок с двумя дочерними элементами и при помощи transform: translate вынести его контент за пределы экрана? Тем самым избавив себя от заморочек с after и от лишних hover`ov. В целом, см. пример в ответах.

Comment: Я даже не подозревал, что можно таким методом решить это задание, с помощью задач узнаю много нового. Спасибо вам!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.aside {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
  transition: transform .5s;

}

.aside:hover {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.aside__header {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  background-color: orange;
  /*margin-top: 400px;*/
  padding: 4px 2px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.aside__content {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(33, 32, 36);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="aside">
    <div class="aside__content">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, eligendi!</div>
    <div class="aside__header">Обратная связь</div>
</div>
```